# For one key value count the occurrences of other key values in list of dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am creating a sublist of dictionaries from a large list with only 2 keys. My data is something like this:

`[{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' } , {'query_name': 'google.com','ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'}, {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'}]`

I want to find out the number of unique occurrences of 'ip4_address' for a particular 'query_name' and merge all 'ip4_address' into single dictionary

Example of output:

`['query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' ,'2.2.2.2', '3.3.3.3', 'count': '3' }]`

Here is my code:

```
reader = DataFileReader(open((os.path.join('active_dns', filename)), "rb"), DatumReader())

for user in reader:
    keys = ['query_name', ,'ip4_address']
    all_values =dict((key, user[key]) for key in keys)
    a_lst.append(all_values)
```

So far I have tried this to compare both the keys and increment the counter for duplicate values:

```
counterdict = defaultdict(list)

for d in a_lst:
       counterdict[d['ip4_address']][d['query_name']] += 1
```

But No desired result so far. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you explain the difference between your desired result and what you actually get?  I notice your code never even *tries* to create an element with the key `count`.

Comment: I get an error while using `counterdict = defaultdict(list)` as **TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not str** .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve your desired result using the following:

```
from collections import defaultdict
a_lst=[{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' } , 
{'query_name': 'google.com','ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'}, {'query_name': 
'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'},{'query_name': 'yahoo.com', 
'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'}]

query_dict=defaultdict(set)
for d in a_lst:
  query_dict[d['query_name']].add(d['ip4_address'])

counterlist = []
for q in query_dict:
  cdict={}
  cdict['query_name'] = q
  cdict['ip4_address'] = list(query_dict[q])
  cdict['count'] = len(cdict['ip4_address'])
  counterlist.append(cdict)

print(counterlist)
```

The output would be:

```
[{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': ['3.3.3.3', '2.2.2.2', '1.1.1.1'], 'count': 3}, {'query_name': 'yahoo.com', 'ip4_address': ['3.3.3.3'], 'count': 1}]
```

Comment: Thank you, @Swetha Shanmugam, this is the most accurate answer and works like a charm. Can you please explain why you chose **set** for defaultdict

Comment: since you've mentioned that you needed a count of all the unique IP addresses, I've used a **set**. That way you don't have to do a duplicate IP check.

Comment: Hi, can you tell me how can I more keys in **query_dict** variable as my original dictionary has more keys.

Answer (score 0):

So this can be achieved through the use of [`itertools.groupby`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby). There is one caveat however, the data must be pre-sorted for this to work.

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

data = [{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' } , {'query_name': 'google.com','ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'}, {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'}, {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' }, {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' }]

query = itemgetter('query_name')
ip = itemgetter('ip4_address')

def custom_sort(obj):
    q = query(obj)
    i = ip(obj)
    return (q, i)

for k, v in groupby(sorted(data, key=custom_sort), key=custom_sort):
    base = {'query_name': k[0], 'ip4_address': k[1]}
    base.update({'count': len(list(v))})
    print(base)

{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1', 'count': 3}
{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '2.2.2.2', 'count': 1}
{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3', 'count': 1}
```

Comment: hi @aws_apprentice, thank you for your answer, can you please suggest, how to merge all of the unique 'ip4_address' into one single dictionary with one single key 'query_name' of 'google.com'? Thanks.

Comment: seems like you just edited for a different output, you can remove the condition for ip4 being a group by condition

Answer (score 0):

you can do this easily using pandas.

```
import pandas as pd
l = [{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' } , {'query_name': 'google.com','ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'}, {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'},{'query_name': 'yahoo.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.2' }]
df = pd.DataFrame(l)
ips=df.groupby(by='query_name')['ip4_address'].value_counts()
ip_dict=ips.to_dict()
```

Comment: Hi, your code does returns count as 1 for all the 'query_name' even for the duplicate values. Here is sample output
**('alecjstern.com.', '198.185.159.144'): 1, ('alecjstern.com.', '198.185.159.145'): 1,**

Comment: Check your example; for  `l = [{'query_name': 'alecjstern.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1' } , {'query_name':'alecjstern.com','ip4_address': '1.1.1.1'}]` I get `{('alecjstern.com', '1.1.1.1'): 2}`  .  Your example doesnt show the input and is hence inconclusive.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another approach.

```
data = [{'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1'},
        {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'},
        {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'}]

def get_ip4(data_list, query_name):
    return { x["ip4_address"] for x in data_list if x["query_name"]==query_name }

query_name = "google.com"

my_desired_output = {k: v for k, v in 
    zip(['query_name', 'ip4_address', 'count'],
        [query_name, list(get_ip4(data, query_name)), len(list(get_ip4(data, query_name)))])}
```

Answer (score 0):

Uhm, what about the "on-the-nose" solution?

```
data = [
    {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '1.1.1.1'},
    {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '2.2.2.2'},
    {'query_name': 'google.com', 'ip4_address': '3.3.3.3'}
]

query_name = "google.com"

ip_addresses = [d["ip4_address"] for d in data if d["query_name"] == query_name]

new_data = {
    "query_name": query_name,
    "ip4_address": ip_addresses,
    "count": str(len(ip_addresses))
}
```

It's not immediately obvious from your desired output if `ip_addresses` should be a tuple or a list. I'm sure you know how to cast a list to a tuple.